# SSRS - The total of percentages doesn't match exactly 100%

Tags: ssrs-2012

Is there a way to have percentages match the exact total of 100% in ssrs when you round it off with 2 digits after the comma?

I tried several things which I found on the internet, like converting my value to a double first, but I still have 0.01% error in my report.

The code that I am using is:

```
=FormatPercent(CDbl((SUM(IIF(Fields!Schedule.Value = "Dismantled", 0, 1)) / ReportItems!TextboxTotal.Value)),2)
```

And the result is:

[image]

I have added an extra column where you can see the entire value (not rounded off)).

Answer (score 0):

If you are dividing a decimal or double by an integer, you might have rounding issues. Can you try using a expression by converting the denominator also to the same format and type as the numerator and calculate the percentages.

```
= FormatPercent(CDbl(SUM(IIF(Fields!Schedule.Value =  "Dismantled", 0, 1)),2)/ CDbl(ReportItems!TextboxTotal.Value,2))
```